# Azure DevOps stage to stage dependency using output variable in condition not working

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipleline with one stage that is dependant upon two others. This stage should run conditionally if both of the following are true -

- Stage 1 (Deploy_BVT_UKS_Internal) sets an output variable with a specific value in one of it's jobs.
- Stage 2 (Test_BVT) either failed or was skipped.

Here is the condition that I am using. However, it is not working and the stage is being skipped when I expect it to run. The syntax for checking the value of the output variable was taken from the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies).

```
condition: >-
  and(
    in(dependencies.Test_BVT.result, 'Skipped', 'Failed'),
    eq(dependencies.Deploy_BVT_UKS_Internal.outputs['Swap_Slots.Output_Slot_Swap_Success_Variable.slotSwapped'], 'true')
  )
```

To confirm, I'm formatting the output variable check as follows -

```
dependencies.<stageName>.outputs['<jobName>.<taskName>.<variableName>']
```

If I simply use `in(dependencies.Test_BVT.result, 'Skipped', 'Failed')` as my condition then the stage runs if the `Test_BVT` stage is skipped or fails. So this suggests that the output variable check is the issue, though I can't be as logs no longer seem to show how conditions are evaluated.

Confusingly the same [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#dependencies) shows stage dependencies formatted in two different ways, so I have added a task to write the value of the output variable using both formats. The format that uses `stageDependencies` produces the expected result, proving that the output variable is being set as expected. However, the format that uses `dependencies` does not work.

```
- job: test
  variables:
    one: $[dependencies.Deploy_BVT_UKS_Internal.outputs['Swap_Slots.Output_Slot_Swap_Success_Variable.slotSwapped']]
    two: $[stageDependencies.Deploy_BVT_UKS_Internal.Swap_Slots.outputs['Output_Slot_Swap_Success_Variable.slotSwapped']]
  steps:
  - script: |
      echo $(one)
      echo $(two)
    displayName: Output SlotSwapped Value
```

I did try the `stageDependencies` format in my condition, just in case, but that also failed.

Am I missing something here, or does this just not worked as documented?

Comment: On the stage level you should use `dependencies` level and on the job level `stageDependencies` to refer to previous stages

Comment: So while that is just really confusing, that would mean that my condition is (in theory) formatted correctly?

Comment: Yeap. Can you check my answer.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This all depends on the context where you want to use dependency to previous stage:

- if you use this on stage level - you should use syntax with `dependencies` like here:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true"
     # or on Windows:
     # - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar

- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.A.outputs['A1.printvar.shouldrun'], 'true'))
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Stage B
```

- but on the job level you should use `stageDependencies` syntax like here:

```yaml
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true"
     # or on Windows:
     # - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    condition: in(stageDependencies.A.A1.result, 'Succeeded', 'SucceededWithIssues', 'Skipped')
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Job B1
  - job: B2
    condition: eq(stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['printvar.shouldrun'], 'true')
    steps:
     - script: echo hello from Job B2
```

As it is written in the link you gave:

> The context is called `dependencies` for jobs and stages and works much like variables. Inside a job, if you refer to an output variable from a job in another stage, the context is called `stageDependencies`.

I made more tests and it looks like a bug. It all depends on the order in your condition. Please compare this

```
condition: and(eq(dependencies.B.outputs['B1.printvar.shouldrun'], 'true'), in(dependencies.A.result, 'Failed', 'Skipped')) # it works
```

and this

```
condition: and(in(dependencies.A.result, 'Failed', 'Skipped'), eq(dependencies.B.outputs['B1.printvar.shouldrun'], 'true')) # it doesn't work
```

It should give the same output but it's not.

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  condition: false
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: echo Job A1
- stage: B
  condition: always()
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
     - bash: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true"
     # or on Windows:
     # - script: echo ##vso[task.setvariable variable=shouldrun;isOutput=true]true
       name: printvar

- stage: C
  condition: and(eq(dependencies.B.outputs['B1.printvar.shouldrun'], 'true'), in(dependencies.A.result, 'Failed', 'Skipped')) # it works
  dependsOn:
  - A
  - B
  jobs:
  - job: C1
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Stage C

- stage: D
  condition: and(in(dependencies.A.result, 'Failed', 'Skipped'), eq(dependencies.B.outputs['B1.printvar.shouldrun'], 'true')) # it doesn't work
  dependsOn:
  - A
  - B
  jobs:
  - job: D1
    steps:
    - script: echo hello from Stage D
```

[image]

Comment: Unbelievably, you are correct. Given that, regardless of order, the conditions should in theory be `(and(true, true))` I'm very surprised. Hopefully this is something MS will fix! Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I created a ticket on developer community for this [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1236160/and-condition-on-stage-level-is-incorrectly-evaulu.html). I wonder what feedback we get.

Comment: @DavidGard it seem that MS fixed thae issue, and it should be rolled out over next few weeks.

Comment: @KrzysztofMadej I just ran into this issue just now. So a quick update: this is not yet fixed so everybody has to keep in mind the `dependencies` vs `stageDependencies` when dealing with this.

Comment: Sad to hear that. Thanks for reply!